# sending a servlet request from javascript to java gives a "Requested Resource not available"

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I want to send a servletRequest from an onClick event in javascript..
This is the code:

```
function switchLanguage(languageRequest) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "changeLanguage", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert("Zumindest das klappt");
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

the JavaCode looks like this:

```
package com.bmw.webevn2.www;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Es kommt zumindes an!");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
//      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String message = "Das schicken klappt";
        response.getWriter().write(message);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {  
        doPost(req, res);  
      }
}
```

When i try to send it it gives me a 404 "The requested resource () is not available."
Am I missing something?

My Web.xml looks like this (part of it):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LanguageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bmw.webevn2.www.ServletController</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LanguageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/changeLanguage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**EDIT**
the link from where it is sent looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="switchLanguage('language')" target="_self">English</a>
```

when I try to access it via `http://localhost:10020/webevn/app/changeLanguage`
it works now, but I want to use a link...

Comment: Where is the servlet declaration for LanguageServlet?  You show the code for ServletController, the declaration for LoginServlet and the mapping for LanguageServlet.  Where is LanguageServlet?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you use in

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "changeLanguage", true);
```

is relative to the current URL of the javascript. So check that the URL path to the javascript and the servlet is the same.

For example if your js is retrieved at the url `xyz.com/js/my.js`, the call will request on `xyz.com/js/changeLanguage`, while it should be `xyz.com/changeLanguage` instead.

Comment: So if the js-file is placed in WeContent -> static -> js I have to call xmlhttp.open("GET", "static/js/changeLanguage", true) ...?

Comment: According to your question, the servlet responds to requests at /webevn/app/changeLanguage.  Therefore, request /webevn/app/changeLanguage in your xmlhttprequest instead of just "changeLanguage".

Comment: @bethlis this is not the path of the file in your project in itself that matters, it is the URL used by the browser to access it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to add the full address of the WebApp to the xmlhttpRequest you can just begin the url with "/". This will send the request to the base of your WebApp.

In your case it should be:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/changeLanguage", true);
```

If the JS file is served from the same folder as the Servlet there should be no JS but a Java problem.